# Vehicle audio recording

Tags: software-engineering, audio

So I red an article on "The sound effect" website about recording the audio of a vehicle. I'm planning on making a race game in the future and I'm having a little concern about the sound of the vehicles and I want to ask is what if you have not seen the car for lamboghini veneno in your life let alone record it. How do you go with it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about the recording setup used for capturing car audio, not game development.